# Задача / Batch (CMD/BAT)

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Кто может помочь?

Пакетный файл, предназначенный для углубленной проверки жесткого диска с созданием файла отчета, путь к которому задаеся в качестве пакетного параметра. Проверка жесткого диска осуществляется ежедневно в 21:00. В течение 20 секунд по окончании проверки диска выводится сообщение "проверка диска завершена. Файл-отчет находится в каталоге <путь>" и далее осуществляется автоматическая перезагрузка системы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так: (и сохранил как Lab.bat)

```
@echo off
chkdsk i: > i:\Log_del.txt
cmd /u /c type i:\Log_del.txt>i:\Log.txt
del /q /s i:\Log_del.txt
Echo Scanning is finished
ping -n 20 127.0.0.1 > nul
shutdown -f -r -t 20
```

и что-то такое я написал для расписания:

```
schtasks /create /sc daily /st 21:00:00 /tr D:\Lab.bat
```

Answer (score 2):

Я могу помочь.

**Для запуска сценария требуется консоль с правами администратора**

Сценарий выглядит приблизительно так:

```
@ECHO OFF

    SET REPORT_PATH=%1 &:: Пакетный параметр к файлу отчёта
    SET TIME_CHECKING_HDD="21:00" &:: Запланированное время начала проверки диска
    SET CURRENT_TIME=%TIME:~0,5% &:: Получаем время в часах

    IF %CURRENT_TIME% EQU %TIME_CHECKING_HDD% (
        CHKDSK > %REPORT_PATH%
        ECHO Проверка диска завершена && TIMEOUT /T 20 > NUL
        ECHO.
        ECHO Файл-отчет находится в каталоге %REPORT_PATH%
        ECHO.
        ECHO Перезагрузка системы произойдёт через 30 секунд
        shutdown -r -t 30
    )
```

Для команды [chkdsk](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chkdsk.mspx?mfr=true) сами прописываете пути, ключи, аргументы. Ну а дальше через  планировщик заданий ([SCHTASKS.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx)) создаёте расписание для выполнения сценария приведённого вам выше.